# Copy unversioned file after git push

Tags: git, githooks

I have a local repository where I work daily and a remote bare repository where I push my result. I would like after every push to copy some local files that are not under version control (like .exe and .dll files) into a separate directory (bin directory for example) on the same server, is it possible?
I tried with hooks but those work server-side, hence I don't know how to tell where the files to copy are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git's hooks aren't necessarily "server-side" - you can have hooks in any repository.  However, there isn't a hook which is run specifically after you've done a `git push` from a repository.  Something that might be close enough is a `post-commit` hook, so that every time you create a commit locally, you could copy the `.exe` and `.dll` files into a separate directory.

However, if you really do just want to copy after pushing, the simplest solution might be to set up a git alias.  For instance, if you do:

```
git config alias.push-and-copy \
    '!sh -c "git push origin master && cp *.dll *.exe ~/bin"'
```

... you can just do:

```
git push-and-copy
```

... in your repository, and the files will be copied if the push was successful.  (I haven't tested that alias, but I think that's right.)

Comment: yeah, I could do this, that are a useful solution, but if the first can do overhead unnecessary in my network, the second isn't very clear if I use TortoiseGIT. In finally I think I use the second, thanks Mark